# Voltage-Source in Feedbackpath of Opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to calculate \$U+,U-,U_A,P_Q\$ of the following Circuit:

[image: Circuit]

I have redrawn the Circuit to:

[image: Circuit2]

For an ideal Opamp, there is no current into it so:

\$i_{R=10k} = \frac{4V}{10k} = 400\mu A\$

\$P_Q = 1.6mA\$

As the Potential at Virtual Ground is the same as at \$U_-\$ i can say:

\$ U_+ = U_- = U_Q = U_A \cdot \frac{30k}{20k+10k}\$

so: \$ U_A = 4V \cdot \frac{20k+10k}{30k}=6.6V\$

but Falstad-Circuit-Simulator dont show me my calculated Values..
what I am doing wrong?

Here is the Falstad-Circuit Link: [Circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Ag%20-32%20160%20-80%20160%200%0Ar%20-16%20160%2048%20160%200%2010000%0Av%20256%20112%20256%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aa%20112%20176%20256%20176%208%2015%20-15%201000000%207.499687507812303%207.499812504687381%20100000%0Aw%20256%20176%20256%20144%200%0Ar%20256%20192%20256%20240%200%2020000%0Aw%20256%20192%20256%20176%200%0Ar%20256%20288%20256%20352%200%2030000%0Aw%20256%20288%20256%20240%200%0Aw%20256%20288%20112%20288%200%0Aw%20112%20288%20112%20192%200%0Aw%20112%20160%2048%20160%200%0Aw%20-16%20160%20-32%20160%200%0Aw%20112%20160%20112%2080%200%0Aw%20112%2080%20256%2080%200%0Aw%20256%2080%20256%20112%200%0Ag%20256%20352%20256%20384%200%0A)

Comment: Why do you make the initial assumption that there is 4V across the 10k resistor?

Comment: on the left side of the 10k Resistor is Ground, and the potential at the right is 4V

Comment: Not 4V with respect to ground

Comment: ah, the Output Voltage and the VSource in the feedbackpath is in series, so i have to sum them.. ok, i get 6V across R10k, but why is UA wrong?

Comment: Hi .. I noticed that your falstad simulation has 5v source not 4v....

Comment: Your falstad simulation's source is also upside down.

Answer (score 2):

An attempt:
Make use of the fact that there is negative feedback,

Then V+ = V-

V- = Vout - 4

V+= Vout * 30k/(20k + 30k)

Then with the first equation you find Vout.

Comment: Are you not seeing positive feedback ?

Comment: are you not seeing the negative feedback?

Comment: Both feedback are there. Any reason to forget the positive feedback and consider only negative feedback ? Since you say V+ = V- ....

Answer (score 2):

The first line of your answer is where you go wrong.

If the voltage across the 10k resistor is 4 volts, then the output of the op amp must be zero wrt ground. And this is not necessarily the case.

Start by assuming that the voltage across the 20k is 4 volts. This in turn assumes that the op amp is operating normally, and maintaining the voltage difference between the inputs at zero (or very close to it).

Comment: but why is the Voltage across the 20k 4V?

Comment: @adaptive - Because, if the op amp is working in its linear range (not a comparator) U- and U+ will be at essentially the same voltage. So the two feedback voltages will be identical. Not perfectly, since the open-loop gain is not infinite, but very close since the gain is high. Consider that, if the output is at 5 volts and the gain is 1 million, the difference between U+ and U- is going to be microvolts.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit does not seem useful... but I will use it as an example how an unknown circuit can be intuitively understood by means of heuristic techniques introduced in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/474572/61398. The advantage of this approach over formal analysis is that, after its implementation, you will not only know the answer to the question but also will understand the circuit.

Following this scenario, I have redrawn the circuit diagram to make it easier to visualize the invisible electrical quantities by voltage bars (in red) and current loops (in green). In addition to the real op-amp circuit (left), I have also drawn an equivalent electrical circuit (right) where the op-amp is emulated through a variable voltage source.

[image: Voltage source in feedback]

**Balanced bridge.** Drawn in this way, this electronic circuit diagram reminds us of something familiar from electrical circuits - *bridge circuit*. This is a balanced bridge since its output voltage is kept zero by varying the input supply voltage VOA. In the first picture, the op-amp varies it; in the second picture a man can do this routine work. Both they (the op-amp and man) do the same - they observe the voltage difference V(-) - V(+) and change VOUT until zero it. The op-amp does it directly while the man needs a zero-voltage indicator (sensitive voltmeter) to see the difference.

The main property of the balanced bridge is that voltages (drops) across the respective opposite elements of the two branches are equal; so VQ = VR3 and V(-) = V(+). We are interested in the first equality because VR3 is the output of the voltage divider R2-R3 (referenced to VOUT)... and as though a copy of the voltage VQ is applied to resistor R3 (to the output of the “turned voltage divider”). So, we conclude VQ = VOUT.R3/(R2 + R3) = VOUT.2/5; or VOUT = 10 V.

But will the op-amp and man manage to balance the bridge?

**Mixed feedback.** We are gradually becoming aware that there is a feedback here. Even more, we see two feedbacks - *negative* (the R1-VQ network between the op-amp output and inverting input) and *positive* (the R2-R3 network between the output and non-inverting input). Both they transfer a part of the output voltage to the op-amp inputs but the negative feedback network only "shifts down" the output voltage with VQ (without attenuation) while the positive feedback network attenuates it R2/(R2 + R3) times. So, when VOUT varies, V(-) will vary more vigorously than V(+)... and the negative feedback will dominate over the positive one. The difference between the two parts is the differential input voltage of the op-amp that will decrease up to zero. The circuit is stable and can reach the equilibrium.

**Weird non-inverting amplifier.** Once understood this circuit, we can conduct more experiments. For example, we can consider VQ as an input source which voltage is amplified R2/R3 + 1 times. Thus we have invented a weird non-inverting amplifier based on positive instead of negative feedback. Indeed, it is turned upside down but it still works.

**More variations.**  If we continue our experiments, we can replace for a while the voltage source VQ with a charged large capacitor... or with a Zener diode (the 10 k resistor will be necessary)... or with something else that can keep constant voltage.

**Negative impedance converter.** Finally, we can swapp VQ and R1... thus inventing the more sophisticated *current-inversion negative impedance converter* (INIC). The experience we have gained so far will allow us to explain *what* a NIC does, *why* it does it, and *how* it does all this...

[image: INIC]

Comment: I just cannot believe, you do these drawings each time.

Comment: And what is weird here:)? I (can) present every circuit in this way. The idea is to overlap the colorful voltages and currents over the black & white circuit diagram... to make the invisible electrical quantities visible...

Comment: nothing is wrong of course, I just admire your motivation and also that skillfull drawing :)

Comment: It would be wonderful if circuit simulators can output results in such a way... I have to suggest this idea to CircuitLab.

Comment: +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but for some reason this question appeared to me and I haven`t find a solution on the answers.

Instead, as you did, use a voltage divider to find U<sup>+</sup>, but using the correct values. This way, you have: $$ U^{-} = U^{+} = U_a \times\frac{30\,\text{k}\Omega}{30\,\text{k}\Omega\,+\,20\text{k}\Omega} = 0.6\,\times\,U_a $$.

Now, on the 4V supply branch, we have:
$$ U^- \,-\, U_a \,=\,4~~~~~\longrightarrow~~~~~U_a = \frac{4}{-0.4} = -10 \,\text{V}~~~thus~~~U^-=U^+=-6\,\text{V} $$.

As to calculating **P<sub>Q</sub>** , the input current on the non-inverting terminal is 0 A. This way, the current through the 4V supply is the same on the resistor:
$$I_q = I_r = \Bigg(\frac{U^--0}{10\,\text{k}\Omega}\Bigg)~~\longrightarrow~~ P_q = U_q \, \times\, \Bigg(\frac{U^--0}{10\,\text{k}\Omega}\Bigg) = \frac{4\,\times(-6)}{10\,\text{k}\Omega} = -2.4~~\text{mW}$$

This is right circuit, using as reference the first image on your question.

[image]

Comment: The 10k resistor does nothing and can be removed; this will not affect the output voltage.